# How to add parameters to a Stripe trigger in the console?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm testing Stripe webhooks locally and I can send a webhook to my server from the Stripe app. If I want to send a 'payout.created' webhook with data (ex. id, status, etc) how would I add those fields?

According to the [Stripe doc](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/trigger#trigger-add) I need to use

> --add [resource]:[path1].[path2]=[value]

where it says:

> Add the param path1.path2 to the `resource. Example: --add payment_intent:customer=customerId

I'm not sure I understand this notation.
What does [resource] mean on the doc page in relationship to running/triiggering a payout.created event webhook?

I tried to run it using this line below but it didn't work

> >stripe trigger payout.created -add id=po_1KDJ2***********ifZ1y

If I run

> >stripe trigger -h

I can see there is a flag for -add and it says -add takes a string array, where I can add parameters to the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

[resource] refers to the base object, so in your case the resource would be `payout`. You then specify the path to the argument that you'd like to provide, using the `.` to step into child parameters.

However, I don't think you're able to set parameters such as `id` that are generated automatically.

For example, the below line returned the associated error:
`stripe trigger payout.created --add payout:id=po_12345`
"message": "Received unknown parameter: id",

But, that error is not encountered when I attempt to specify an `amount` instead of the `id`.
`stripe trigger payout.created --add payout:amount=5000`

Comment: oh ok, good to know. I'll do more research to see what I can pass in. I guess I'll just have to reset the id in the debug console.

Comment: Are you able to tell me which resource I can use for when I'm adding metadata for a customer subscription update? The metadata is not coming through. My attempt is this: `stripe trigger customer.subscription.updated --add customer_subscription:metadata['Environment']=dev`

Comment: These days I would suggest using the `--edit` option when running the `trigger` command to bring up the fixtures the Stripe CLI uses in your default editor so you can change them. You can then edit the fixture to include metadata on the desired object.