# What is the correct Stripe resource to supply in the metadata when updating a subscription cli callback request?

Tags: stripe-payments

I can't figure out how to make a request to using the Stripe API cli callback tool* to include my required metadata in my update subscription request. I have this:

`stripe trigger customer.subscription.updated --add customer_subscription:metadata['Environment']=dev`

I suspect the issue is in the `customer_subscription` resource but I've tried every combination and have had no success. I have been following (among others) this example: [How to add parameters to a Stripe trigger in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70950758/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-stripe-trigger-in-the-console)

*https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add metadata to the subscription, I believe this the command that you need to run

`stripe trigger customer.subscription.updated --add subscription:metadata['Environment']=dev`

Comment: Yes, that's it. I'm sure I tried that. Thank you.